# Increase product stock on sale

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to make something different with my Magento instance;

I want to increase product's stock (in a certain condition) when I'm selling a product. I've added a custom checkbox in the Magento Admin panel and when it's checked I expect to increase product's quantity.

I'm currently investigating the following method:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote:submitOrder()
```

Is it a good place to start looking at? Any tip on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've achieved what I wanted.

I've added the following lines at `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote:submitOrder()`

```
    ...
    // $mySpecialCondition = form.checkbox
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if($mySpecialCondition){
            $item->setQty(0 - $item->getQty(), true);
        }
    ...
```

and also changed the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item:_prepareQty` to accept negative values:

```
protected function _prepareQty($qty, $ignoreValue = false)
{
    $qty = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getNumber($qty);
    if(!$ignoreValue){
        $qty = ($qty > 0) ? $qty : 1;
    }
    return $qty;
}
```

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: that's not a good way to go about it, try using an event/observer

Comment: take a look at the sales_order_place_after event there's a few examples of setting up an observer. it would be a nicer solution and not invlove touching any core code.